# Live Stream GlSurfaceview with Camera Preview using WebRTC in Android

Tags: android, webrtc, glsurfaceview

I have to live stream my camera preview on GlSurfaceview.

At the same time I want to put objects on my camera preview surface, draw text on the surface and live stream that all using WebRTC.

I am using below GitHub sample for WebRTC.
https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

From the above sample, I can stream my surface but not working drawing text on the surface and stream that simultaneously.

I have tried to customize Renderer class to draw text and stream but it's not working.

If anyone can help on this.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: so do you have a solution?